# Is there a way to disable a sublist field while choosing dropdown value from the same sublist. SuiteScript 2.0 getSublistField method not working

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am required to disable one of the filed from a list dynamically while choosing the option from dropdown. Example i have main category value as  accomodation and a field in the same line as number of days stay. the stay field is diabled while creating itself. i want to enable this line item field only when accomodation is choosed in the dropdown menu.

I have tried using getSublistFiled to get the stay field refernce but it is showing an error and also isDisabled.

```
  var fld1 = currentRecord.getSublistField({
                    sublistId: 'recmachcustrecord_expse_clm_itm_parent',
                    fieldId: 'custrecord_expse_clm_itm_sub_catgry',
                    line: currentLine
                });
                fld1.isDisabled = true;
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by nlapiDisableLineItemField.

```
nlapiDisableLineItemField('recmachcustrecord_expse_clm_itm_parent','custrecord_expse_clm_itm_stay', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using currentRecord.**getCurrentSublistValue**. You should use currentRecord.**getSublistField**.

Comment: currentRecord.getSublistField this is giving me error. INVALID Expression